# Not Work Opcache on Wampserver 2.4

Tags: php, wampserver, apc, opcache

i add this following code in php.ini

```
    [opcache]
    zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.16/ext/php_opcache.dll"
    opcache.enable = 1
    opcache.memory_consumption = 300
    opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 8
    opcache.max_accelerated_files = 8000
    opcache.fast_shutdown = 1
    opcache.enable_cli = 1
    opcache.use_cwd = 1
```

but not working.

Comment: opcache does not come by default with php5.4.16 so where did you get the php_opcache.dll from?

Comment: You also will need to ensure you get the Thread Safe version to run with WAMPServer i.e. `-ts-` and not `-nts-`

Comment: i used -ts ver. of .dll file.

Comment: But which dll did you down load

Comment: You probably need the VC9 version rather than the VC11 one

Comment: php_opcache.dll -ts. version.

Comment: Download from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/opcache/

Comment: ok sir i 'll try.

Comment: php_opcache-7.0.5-5.3-ts-vc9-x86 i use this file of dll but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download

```
php_opcache-7.0.5-5.3-ts-vc9-x86.zip
                  ^^^
```

is for PHP5.3

You say you are using PHP5.4 so you need the

```
php_opcache-7.0.5-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip
                  ^^^
```